# Why did the Causality Violation Device behave this way in Version Control?

Tags: version-control

Throughout Dexter Palmer's book, *Version Control*, when the team performs experiments with the CVD, they never see any evidence that the machine had done anything, the clock on the robot was always consistent.

> At one point, they explained this by saying that history changed and the robot was actually sent an hour later this time around, but why would that be the case? They did this experiment hundreds of times, and in each one, history happens to shift just the right amount to make it look like nothing happened? I guess it's also assumed that the hour difference is okay because of how they keep bringing up that matter can be temporarily borrowed or loaned, and an hour falls in that threshold? Rebecca popping out at the end seemed to completely break any restriction on imperceptibly swapping out histories, but they had done plenty of runs with humans before and never seen anything, so it isn't just that she is human.

Comment: Can you try and not have all of the question pretty much hidden in a spoiler block. As I'm not familiar with the work I don't really want to edit it but could you try and move some of it out?

Comment: What if everything in that spoiler block happens in the last fifth of the book? I'm not sure how careful I need to be with spoilers and there wasn't much guidance on the help page so I opted to be more careful.

Comment: More careful is certainly the proper approach but a question should be able to be mostly understood without having to read the spoilers. Or rather one should be able to find out what sort of content the spoiler block is likely to give away before they hover over it. Placement in the book doesn't matter too much, more the content of what is a "spoiler".